# SQL Server get next previous rows from a table based on a date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following SQL Server query and I am trying to get the next and previous row from a given Id. All works great unless there are two/more dates that are the same, then my logic breaks down.

If you set @currentId = 4 then I get back id 7 (it should be id 6) for the prev

If you set @currentId = 6 then I get back id 2 (it should be id 4) for the next

```
declare @t table (i int, d datetime)
insert into @t (i, d)
select 1, '17-Nov-2009 07:22:13' union
select 2, '18-Nov-2009 07:22:14' union
select 3, '17-Nov-2009 07:23:15' union
select 4, '20-Nov-2009 07:22:18' union
select 5, '17-Nov-2009 07:22:17' union
select 6, '20-Nov-2009 07:22:18' union
select 7, '21-Nov-2009 07:22:19'

--order that I want
select * from @t order by d desc, i

declare @currentId int; set @currentId = 4

--Get Prev
select TOP 1 * from @t where d > (select TOP 1 d from @t where i = @currentId order by d, i desc) order by d, i desc

--Get Next
select TOP 1 * from @t where d < (select TOP 1 d from @t where i = @currentId order by d desc) order by d desc
```

Can anyone help me work out how to guarantee get the next/prev row based on a given id, Note that it is important that I keep the this order, Date Desc, id ASC

Many thanks

**EDIT:** It should be noted that this is going to be used for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there ... try this instead. Effectively changed the date comparison to be "*...-or-equals-to*" and telling it not to match the current ID so it doesn't return the same row...

```
declare @currID int
set @currID = 4

select top 1 *
from (
    select * 
        from @t
        where d = (select d from @t where i = @currID)
            and i > @currID
    union ALL
    select * 
        from @t
        where d < (select d from @t where i = @currID)
) as t
order by d desc, i

select top 1 *
from (
    select * 
        from @t
        where d = (select d from @t where i = @currID)
            and i < @currID
    union ALL
    select * 
        from @t
        where d > (select d from @t where i = @currID)
) as t
order by d, i desc
```

Comment: Chris thanks for this, I am struggling to make this work as the schema is different. I can see what you are suggesting though.

Comment: Different to...? This should work with the example table and data you've provided above :-) I assume you need to adapt this to a live schema?

Comment: My mistake -- had a typo in my SQL (serves me right for editing the SQL in stackoverflow to clean it up after I'd tested it elsewhere). It will work now...!

Comment: @Rippo -- I think I've nailed this. I've worked down the sequences as provided and it looks like it's coming out correctly as per what you want. Give this version a run.

Comment: Excellant, thanks for sticking with this....
Now I got to turn it into a Linq query :)

Answer (score 0):

Toy can try something like this

```
    declare @t table (i int, d datetime)
        insert into @t (i, d)
        select 1, '17-Nov-2009 07:22:13' union
        select 2, '18-Nov-2009 07:22:14' union
        select 3, '17-Nov-2009 07:23:15' union
        select 4, '20-Nov-2009 07:22:18' union
        select 5, '17-Nov-2009 07:22:17' union
        select 6, '20-Nov-2009 07:22:18' union
        select 7, '21-Nov-2009 07:22:19'

        --order that I want
        select * from @t order by d desc, i

        declare @currentId int; 
        set @currentId = 4



SELECT  TOP 1 t.*
FROM    @t t INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  d CurrentDateVal
                FROM    @t
                WHERE   i = @currentId
            ) currentDate ON t.d <= currentDate.CurrentDateVal AND t.i != @currentId
    ORDER BY t.d DESC

    SELECT  t.*
FROM    @t t INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  d CurrentDateVal
                FROM    @t
                WHERE   i = @currentId
            ) currentDate ON t.d >= currentDate.CurrentDateVal AND t.i != @currentId
    ORDER BY t.d
```

You must be carefull, it can seem that 6 should be both prev and next.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have run your answer and get 6 and 4 back from the current Id of 4, I should expect 7(prev) and 6(next) if currentId is 4....

Comment: Made some changes. Have a look

Comment: Looks like this has nailed it. I tried the <= and >= but did not think to exclude the current Id... thanks

Comment: Actually spoke to soon, try currentId of 6!

Comment: What do you need for prev and next when useing id 4? and prev next for id 6?

Comment: The order of the id's are based on the date desc e.g. 7,4,6,2,3,5,1
If I say have an current id of 4 I would want to return 7 (the previous one) and 6 (the next one). This is what I am trying to achieve.